# laravel load vuejs components only on the page i need them

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

at the moment we are loading all of our components in the `app.js` using

```
Vue.component('ID', path-to-component);
```

This means if we have a failure in one of the component is breaks all the components.

so is there a way to load the component on the specific page we require them?

I tried pushing it to a stack in the blade but it errors with

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined vuejs

My code is:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script>
        Vue.component('BookingPayments' ,  require('./components/bookings/bookings-payments'));
    </script>
@endpush
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use [lucasmazza/page.js](https://github.com/lucasmazza/page.js) to load javascript code only on specific URLs. You can scope your code like:

```
page.at('payments', () => {
    Vue.component('BookingPayments', require('...'));
});
```

The library uses a `data-page` attribute on the `body` tag.

You can only use the `require` method on the files being processed by Laravel Mix (webpack).

Answer (score 0):

Just use import option:

```
`Import otherComponent from './component/otherComponent.vue'`
```

So it is not a global component and is available just in this page.